Some logs are not displayed in the index
Logs come to Logstash, are parsed there and then sent to Elasticsearch in index cnv-tariffication-service-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}.
But I don't see all the necessary logs in the index, only a part of them.
I'm also testing a way to fetch logs from the same application via kafka.
But the log data is not visible in the cnv-tariffication-service-%{+YYYYY.MM.dd} index at all, but when I create a new index [cnv-kafka-tariffication-service-%{+YYYY.MM.dd} for instance], I can see it there.
What is the problem?

you can print the output to stdout to check if the missed logs are parsed correctly before sending to elasticsearch
